# Content convert to Frame in UWP with c++

Tags: cocos2d-x, win-universal-app, c++-cx

I have a problem when i try to convert Content Windows::UI::Xaml::Window::Current->Content  ---> Frame.
in c#,i use this way like"Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content as Frame".
but in UWP with C++/CX.I cant find way.I want using Frame->Navigate(TypeName(xx)).

Answer (score 2):

Use a dynamic_cast to convert from a generic type (Object^) to a more defined type (Frame^) without an exception, similar to C#s "as" conversion.

Your scenario is the specific examples given for dynamic_cast in the C++/Cx [casting documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755802.aspx).